# Add breakpoints and install handlers

Tags: macos, breakpoints, ptrace

My high-level goal is something like this:

```
void print_backtrace() {
    void *callstack[128];
    int framesC = backtrace(callstack, sizeof(callstack));
    printf("backtrace() returned %d addresses\n", framesC);
    char** strs = backtrace_symbols(callstack, framesC);
    for(int i = 0; i < framesC; ++i) {
        if(strs[i])
            printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
        else
            break;
    }
    free(strs);
}

install_breakpoint_handler("__NSAutoreleaseNoPool", print_backtrace);
```

So, each time the `__NSAutoreleaseNoPool` function breakpoint is catched, `print_backtrace` should be called. (All within the same binary. I'm not trying to catch the breakpoint of separate processes.)

I guess I can somehow do this via `ptrace`. Is there some easy-to-use and lightweight library?

Currently I'm searching for a MacOSX solution, but cross-platform would be nice of course.

Answer (score 0):

I just found one lib (I even had used it a few years ago...): [mach_override](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_override)

I also found [this debuglib](https://github.com/rofl0r/debuglib) but didn't tried.

See [here](https://github.com/albertz/playground/blob/master/demo_NSAutoreleaseNoPool.mm) for a demonstration for `__NSAutoreleaseNoPool`: It automatically executes `print_backtrace`.